# No one has seen God

Tags: exegesis, trinity, gospel-of-john, apologetics, exodus

How do Trinitarians reconcile John 1:18:

> No one has seen God at any time. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has declared Him

with Exodus 24:9-11:

> Then Moses went up, also Aaron, Nadab, and Abihu, and seventy of the elders of Israel,  and they saw the God of Israel. And there was under His feet as it were a paved work of sapphire stone, and it was like the very heavens in its clarity. But on the nobles of the children of Israel He did not lay His hand. So they saw God, and they ate and drank.

It says Moses, Aaron, Nadab and Abihu and 70 elders saw God...and ate and drank?

Comment: Perhaps of some note, the LXX reads "And they saw the place where the God of Israel stood; and under his feet was as it were a work of sapphire"

Comment: Sometimes, the making of absolute statements such as 'no one', 'at any time' renders interpretation of scripture a little difficult when there are situations where it says otherwise. I don't think we want to succumb to partial interpretations rather than the totality of the message.  No one has seen the 'full form of God', especially His face, except the son might be the rendering but without that qualification it puts Ex. 24: 9-11 as a contradiction, which it isn't.